# How to set checkbox value in rvest::set_values() in R

Tags: r, rvest

I read a html form using `rvest` and wanted to set a checkbox value:
[image]

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.signupgenius.com/go/10c0f4fadac2ea6fac52-release825'
html_form(session(url))[[1]]
<form> 'signupForm' (POST https://www.signupgenius.com/index.cfm?go=s.PreProcessSignup)
  <field> (hidden) URLID: 10C0F4FADAC2EA6FA...
  <field> (hidden) useMultiple: true
  <field> (hidden) siids: 
  <field> (checkbox) siid: 962826833
```

I'm wondering how to set the checkbox value to true using `set_values()`.

Answer (score 1):

The process of submitting the a form involves creating a session, retrieving the form, updating the value, submitting and jumping to the next page.

```
#Based on rvest >1.0.0
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://www.signupgenius.com/go/10c0f4fadac2ea6fac52-release825'
#create the session and retrieve the form
pgsession<-session(url)
pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]

#https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/issues/34
pgform$url<-""

#create the response and set the value of checkbox to TRUE
#another option to try: siid=1
filled_form<-html_form_set(pgform, siid=TRUE) 
#Submitt the  form
session_submit(pgsession, filled_form, submit=NULL)

#may need to manually  naviage to the next page
#next_page<-jump_to(pgsession,"https://www.signupgenius.com/index.cfm?go=s.ProcessSignup&urlid=10C0F4FADAC2EA6FAC52-release825")
```

Give this a try, it should work.  If not please let me know in case it needs an update.

Comment: Thanks but it shows 'Error Oops! Looks like there's none to be processed or you're already done processing this sign up. View the sign up or if you need further assistance, please contact support.' Any suggestions? Have tried ssid=1, ssid='true', ssid=TRUE.